# Using Kotlin library in java android studion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I want to use the chipped bottom navigation by https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar, But it is done in Kotlin. I want to us it in java. How can i use it? What code should I implement.

Comment: Kotlin and Java work very well together. Just treat it the same way you handle any java library, you don't have to do anything fancy.

Comment: from the github you linked it seems you just need to add `implementation 'com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation:chip-navigation-bar:1.2.0'` to your build.gradle

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Please check [Calling Kotlin from Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) official article. Actually each Kotlin construction can be unwrapped to Java (except `inline` function features and couple other).

Actually the coding is the same: add dependency into the project (both `Kotlin` and `Java` uses `jar` files), call methods, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.70'` to your dependencies as well